# Jquery "closest" and "find" functions returns "undefined"!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the value of first `<td>` of the row that the clicked element exist in it. here is the code I use:

The result is "undefined" when function is triggered. where do i wrong?

```js
function verifyOfflinepayment() {
  $("#verifying").show();
  alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>$paymentId</td>
    <td>
      <a href='#modal$i'>مشاهده رسید</a>
    </td>
    <td onclick='verifyOfflinepayment()'>
      $persian_date
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='pretty p-icon p-round p-pulse'>
        <input type='checkbox' />
        <div class='state p-success'>
          <i class='icon mdi mdi-check'></i>
          <label>تایید</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: There is no explicit `this` in inline event functions. `this` will be `window`

Comment: The title is misleading. It's `.html()` that returns `undefined` and not `.find()` or `.closest()`. And for the actual problem. Check the value of `this`

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @charlietfl correct! that was the problem ,thanks

Comment: @Andreas correct too, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the reference of the clicked element in the `verifyOfflinepayment` function like `verifyOfflinepayment(this)`. Currently `$(this)` references your window object so you are getting `undefined`.

```js
function verifyOfflinepayment(elem) {
    $("#verifying").show();
    alert($(elem).closest('tr').find('td:eq(0)').html());
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
      <td>$paymentId</td>
      <td>
        <a href='#modal$i'>مشاهده رسید</a>
      </td>
      <td onclick='verifyOfflinepayment(this)'>
      $persian_date
      </td>
      <td>
         <div class='pretty p-icon p-round p-pulse'>
           <input type='checkbox'  />
           <div class='state p-success' >
              <i class='icon mdi mdi-check' ></i>
              <label>تایید</label>
           </div>
         </div>
      </td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The OP asks for first td data of the tr

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
function verifyOfflinepayment(event) {
  $("#verifying").show();
  alert($(event).parent().find('td').eq(0).html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>$paymentId</td>
    <td>
      <a href='#modal$i'>مشاهده رسید</a>
    </td>
    <td onclick='verifyOfflinepayment(this)'>
      $persian_date
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='pretty p-icon p-round p-pulse'>
        <input type='checkbox' />
        <div class='state p-success'>
          <i class='icon mdi mdi-check'></i>
          <label>تایید</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: You are passing the object but call it event